# Separate the `renderUI` in a module server

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

In some complex and large shiny apps, the UI parts are often rendered with `renderUI` and `uiOutput`. Consider this small app for illustration:

```r
library(shiny)

modUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("theUI"))
}

modServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id, 
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      output[["plot"]] <- renderPlot({
        n <- input[["numb"]]
        plot(rnorm(n), rnorm(n), pch = 19L)
      })
      
      ns <- session$ns
      output[["theUI"]] <- renderUI({
        tagList(
          sliderInput(ns("numb"), "N", 10, 100, 50),
          plotOutput(ns("plot"))
        )
      })
    }
  )
}

ui <- basicPage(
  br(),
  modUI("myapp")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  modServer("myapp")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here `modUI` is ridiculously small. But in `modServer`, the `renderUI` could be large and there could be many other `output` components. Therefore it is desirable to split `modServer`:

```r
renderPlotServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id, 
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      output[["plot"]] <- renderPlot({
        n <- input[["numb"]]
        plot(rnorm(n), rnorm(n), pch = 19L)
      })
      
    }
  )
}

renderUIServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id, 
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      ns <- session$ns
      output[["theUI"]] <- renderUI({
        tagList(
          sliderInput(ns("numb"), "N", 10, 100, 50),
          plotOutput(ns("plot"))
        )
      })
      
    }
  )
}
```

and to put them together one can use the same `id`:

```r
modServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id, 
    function(input, output, session) {
      renderPlotServer("mysubapp")
      renderUIServer("mysubapp")
    }
  )
}
```

but then we need a *nested namespace* in the UI part of the module:

```r
modUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(NS(id)("mysubapp"))
  uiOutput(ns("theUI"))
}
```

This is not convenient.

A more convenient solution consists in using a `NULL` namespace, to avoid the nested namespace in the UI part:

```r
modServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id, 
    function(input, output, session) {
      renderPlotServer(NULL)
      renderUIServer(NULL)
    }
  )
}
```

But this solution has a problem: it prevent to use the module multiple times.

So, what would be a convenient solution avoiding this problem?

I think I have one: one can nest the "main" id with itself:

```r
modServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id, 
    function(input, output, session) {
      renderPlotServer(id)
      renderUIServer(id)
    }
  )
}

modUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(NS(id)(id))
  uiOutput(ns("theUI"))
}
```

Do you have another nice solution?

Answer (score 1):

So maybe I am overlooking some subtleties of your approach, but why would you need to use `moduleServer` in `render(Plot|UI)Server` in the first place? Rather you can go for a plain function and all the namespacing seems to work without any further ado?

```r
library(shiny)

modUI <- function(id) {
   ns <- NS(id)
   uiOutput(ns("theUI"))
}

renderPlotServer <- function(input, output, session) {
   output[["plot"]] <- renderPlot({
      n <- input[["numb"]]
      plot(rnorm(n), rnorm(n), pch = 19L)
   })
}

renderUIServer <- function(input, output, session) {
   ns <- session$ns
   output[["theUI"]] <- renderUI({
      tagList(
         sliderInput(ns("numb"), "N", 10, 100, 50),
         plotOutput(ns("plot"))
      )
   })
   
}

modServer <- function(id) {
   moduleServer(
      id, 
      function(input, output, session) {
         renderPlotServer(input, output, session)
         renderUIServer(input, output, session)
      }
   )
}

ui <- basicPage(
   br(),
   modUI("myapp"),
   br(),
   modUI("myapp2") ## a second module works like a charm
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   modServer("myapp")
   modServer("myapp2")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That's correct but I assumed the possibility to reuse the `render(Plot|UI)Server` multiple times in  `modServer`.  But well, maybe in this case the better and easiest way is to use multiple `modServer` instead. +1

Comment: If you want to reuse it, it deserves to be a full module in its own right. Hence, there should also be a corresponding module UI in this case and you can simply nest your modules.